# check_box manually set to ticked through controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, checkbox, controller

In my index controller I have a bit of logic. Occasionally, I want to set the check_box default to ticked when the page renders.
To do this, I want to pass a param to the view and get the check_box to use this param (true/false) to determine whether to show as ticked or un-ticked.

Can I do this?

Comment: So it's possible that the param you're passing has nothing to do with the checkbox field itself? Meaning, are you trying to pass a param like ?foo=val  and then you'd want to check an input for :bar ? Or is the param related to :bar?

Comment: My below answer should still work.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is this:

Let's say to your `index` page you are passing a param q.

So the url is: `website.com/foo?q=true`

The symbol / field that the checkbox controls for the model `Model` is `:bar`

In your controller, try something like this (**EDITED WITH @Mike's suggestion**):

```
def index
  @model = Model.new
  @model.bar = (params[:q] == "true")
end
```

See if that works. I don't think you'll need any extra logic in your view.

Comment: Even better would be for the line 3 to be simpler by removing the true : false part and leaving it as: @model.bar = (params[:q] == "true")

Comment: I thought there was a shorthand but mindblanked. If you don't mind, Mike, I'll edit the answer?